# Copy multiple sources to multiple destinations simultaneously

Tags: rsync, file-transfer, scp

Suppose I need to copy files

`~/path/to/file` to `user@remote:/path/to/file`

`~/path/to/another/file` to `user@remote:/path/to/another/file`

`~/path/alternative` to `user@remote:/path/alternative`

Is there is a way to do this using `rsync` or `scp`?

I've tried `rsync ~/path/{to/file,to/another/file,alternative} user@remote:/path`

But it's not an option if I need to copy to another dest like `another_path`.

Copying file-by-file is way too long if I need to copy at least 20 files.

Comment: If you don't want to transfer the whole contents of `~/path/` then you should look at rsync's `--files-from` option.

Comment: @wurtel, this is actually the best decision addressing the problem so far. If you answer the question, I will accept.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to transfer a selection of files via rsync, i.e. not the entire directory including contents, then the best way of doing so is by using rsync's `--files-from` option. Place the pathnames of the files you want to transfer, relative to the source directory you specify. See rsync's manpage for more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

This script will copy an arbitrary number of input directories, to an arbitrary number of hosts, *in parallel* through the use of shell background jobs. Here I used *cpio* because it's easy to split and pipe the input files, but you could modify this to use `rsync --files-from` also.

Usage: `multi-cpio.sh <srcfile> <dstfile>`
(requires ssh-keys in place for non-interactive login)

`srcfile` contains one directory per line, such as:

```
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man3
/usr/share/man/man5
```

`dstfile` contains one remote target per line, such as:

```
user@host:/tmp/a
user@host:/tmp/b
user@host:/tmp/c
```

...and the source for `multi-cpio.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash 

SRCLIST=$1
DSTLIST=$2

# create temporary files, safely, in /tmp with mcpio prefix
TEMP=`tempfile -p mcpio`

# loop over input file and create a list of all files to be copied
for I in `cat $SRCLIST` ; do
  find $I -depth -print >>$TEMP
done

# split the file into CPU count + factor
# set to '4' here, seems like ~6x CPIO will max my 1Gb Ethernet link to ~800Mbps in atop
SPLITCOUNT= $(( $( wc -l $TEMP | cut -d' ' -f1) / $(( $( grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l ) + 4 )) ))
split -l $SPLITCOUNT $TEMP $TEMP 


# nested loops, for each target and for each chunk, start a background copy


for DEST in `cat $DSTLIST` ; do
  # this selects the "user@host" from user@host:/target/path
  HOST=$(expr substr $DEST 1 $(($(expr index $DEST :)-1)))
  # this selects the "/target/path" from user@host:/target/path
  DIR=$(expr substr $DEST $(($(expr index $DEST :)+1)) $(expr length $DEST))

  # loop over all the split tempfiles with ${TEMP}??
  for I in ${TEMP}?? ; do
   # use cpio in copy-out mode to stream the files through ssh
   # then ensure the target is in place in the remote host, cd into it,
   # and copy-in the files.
   # note the '&' at the end backgrounds this command, so the loop
   # will continue and generate more concurrent background jobs
   cat $I | cpio -o | ssh $HOST \
     "mkdir $DIR ; cd $DIR && cpio -idum --no-absolute-filenames" & 
   # sleep for a second before the next spawn to allow for ssh auth
   #  and so sshd doesn't start dropping new sessions
   sleep 1
  done
done

# cleanup the tempfiles
rm ${TEMP}??
rm $TEMP
```

See also http://rightsock.com/~kjw/Ramblings/tar_v_cpio.html for additional cpio reference and the inspiration for this script.

Edit: Alternative syntax for just one src dst, without creating srcfile destfile:

```
multi-cpio.sh <(echo "/path/to/src") <(echo "user@host:/path/to/dest")
```